# Using package 'libertine' overrides my sans-font with Libertine instead of Biolinum

Tags: fonts, libertine

I'm trying to use the `libertine` package instead of using the installed Libertine fonts on my machine (macOS). It seems that after adding the `libertine` package, it overrides my sans-serif font and uses Libertine instead of Biolinum.

I have the following layout:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
% \usepackage{libertine}

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont{Linux Biolinum O}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries\LARGE}
  {\filright \sffamily\mdseries
    \fontsize{10em}{0em}\selectfont
    \oldstylenums{\thechapter}}
  {1em}
  {\filright}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\end{document}
```

If I build this with `xelatex`, I get the following output:
[image: without-libertine]

If I uncomment the `\usepackage{libertine}`, this will be rendered instead:
[image: with-libertine]

The big `1` is rendered with the Libertine font instead of Biolinum, even though the `\titleformat` block uses `\sffamily`.

Is there a way I could force the sans-serif rendering?

Comment: Try removing your `\oldstylenums` and loading the libertine package with `osf`.

Comment: @TeXnician oh wow, removing `\oldstylenums` worked!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is `\oldstylenums` which switches the font. Just use the fontspec syntax.

[image: biolinum]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}

%\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
%\setsansfont{Linux Biolinum O}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries\LARGE}
  {\filright \sffamily\mdseries
    \fontsize{10em}{0em}\selectfont
    {\addfontfeature{Numbers=OldStyle}\thechapter}}
  {1em}
  {\filright}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (Still need to wait 5 minutes to accept your answer. Thanks again for the tweak, it looks even better!)

Comment: @IgalTabachnik You're welcome. These are the parts of LaTeX's behaviour the end user will never expect :)

Answer (score 5):

### The `fontspec` Way

The `libertine` package redefines `\oldstylenums{}` to switch the font. You can change back to a definition like the one from `fontspec`, which adds the OpenType font feature to the currently-selected font. Note that this is an incompatibility between the `libertine` and `fontspec` packages!

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}

%% \oldstylenums and \liningums will change the style of the current font, as
%% in fontspec, not switch to the serif font, as in libertine.
\renewcommand\oldstylenums[1]{{\addfontfeatures{Numbers=OldStyle}{#1}}}
\renewcommand\liningnums[1]{{\addfontfeatures{Numbers=Lining}{#1}}}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries\LARGE}
  {\filright \sffamily\mdseries
    \fontsize{10em}{0em}\selectfont
    \oldstylenums{\thechapter}}
  {1em}
  {\filright}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}

\oldstylenums{1234567890} vs. \liningnums{1234567890}.
\end{document}
```

[image: Oldstyle numbers in Libertine and Biolinum]

You could alternatively give the command a new, unambiguous name or save the definitions after loading `fontspec` and before loading `libertine`.

### The `libertine` Way

The `libertine` package provides a second command, `\oldstylenumsf{}`, to switch the font to Biolinum with old-style numbers. You could simply replace `\textsf{\oldstylenums{}}` with `\oldstylenumsf{}`.

Answer (score 4):

The package defines the `\biolinumOsF` font:

```
\usepackage{libertine}
```

and

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries\LARGE}
{\filright\mdseries\fontsize{10em}{0em}\selectfont
  \biolinumOsF\thechapter}
{1em}
{\filright}
```

[image]